# How to solve this error “Optimize SEO Data” in wordpress

Tags: wordpress, optimization, migration, seo, yoast

want to migrate from All In One SEO (AISEO) to Yoast to have better structured results. However, the migration tool is not functioning due to a bug: https://github.com/Yoast/wordpress-seo/issues/16518

I decided to do the migration without waiting for the bug to be resolved. The only hard-to-transfer data is meta descriptions and we will sort them out. So I downloaded Yoast and clicked “Optimize SEO Data”. I got this message afterwards:
“Oops, something has gone wrong and we couldn’t complete the optimization of your SEO data. Please click the button again to re-start the process.

Below are the technical details for the error. See this page for a more detailed explanation.”

Explanations include:
“

There has been a critical error on this website.

Learn more about debugging in WordPress.

”
Hearing from you.

I have changed plugin.

Comment: You need to check error log if you have or enable the log and then share the error message here.

Comment: Error parsing the response to JSON.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.